# Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'

Tags: typescript

I get error when using tsun to test TypeScript.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0L2T.png)

How I can fix??

Comment: You need to provide more info for people to help.

Answer (score 3):

I've also had this error message, but it turns out that if the tsun was installed globally, I only needed to restart my console (in linux). So i guess you should also restart the powershell.